# Not able to print the text without using time.sleep() in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Not able to get the Text with the below code from the print statement in Python Selenium but when i am trying to add time.sleep(4) before print(new_cases.text) statement then i am able to get the text.I am using Explicit wait.Can anyone help me what is the issue here?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://covid-19-dc.herokuapp.com/");
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,120)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of((driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@id='new_case']"))))
new_cases = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@id='new_case']")
print(new_cases.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I am not familiar with selenium wait but the 2 lines begiving by `wait.until` and `news_cases` are a bit strange as they both call `driver.find_element(...)`. If you need a wait for the second one then it seems you already need a wait for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `find_element` in `visibility_of`, use `visibility_of_element_located` instead. `find_element` is executed internally, so the returned value is the `WebElement` you waited for

```
new_cases = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[@id='new_case']"))
```